# How to install HeidiSQL on Ubuntu

Tags: wine, software-installation, gui

I have been using [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) (an open source GUI for MySQL / MSSQL) on Windows for a while now. However, as I'm moving to Ubuntu for development, I'd like to continue using HeidiSQL.

The website states that it can be used with an application called Wine, but there isn't any documentation on how to do this.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

#### Step 1: install Wine

There are three ways how you can get Wine. You can either download the stable version from the official Ubuntu repository, download it from Wine's repository, or compile the source yourself.

The simplest option is probably downloading it from the Ubuntu repository, using the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Follow the instructions, you will need to accept a license agreement for TrueType fonts. Use the arrow keys (<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd>) and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept the terms.

#### Step 2: download HeidiSQL

Download the installer from http://www.heidisql.com/download.php.

#### Step 3: install HeidiSQL using Wine

Open the installer for HeidiSQL with Wine and follow the steps to install the application.

#### Step 4: add the HeidiSQL icon to the launcher (optional)

This step is optional, even without it you can start using HeidiSQL. However, I wanted to add a shortcut to the launcher, but this wasn't as easy as I thought it would be. I finally managed to do so by following these steps:

1. First, find out where Wine is storing the HeidiSQL icon. In my instance, it was in `/home/nic/.local/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps`.
2. You also need the location of the HeidiSQL executable. In my instance, it's in `/home/nic/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/HeidiSQL`.
3. With this information, we can create a new file in `~/.local/share/applications`, called `heidisql.desktop`.

   ```
   sudo gedit ~/.local/share/applications/heidisql.desktop
   ```

   (you can use another text editor instead of gedit, of course).

   Fill it with:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=HeidiSQL
   Comment=HeidiSQL on Ubuntu
   Exec=env WINEDEBUG=-all WINEPREFIX=/home/USER/.wine wine heidisql.exe
   Icon=/home/USER/.local/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/9103_heidisql.0.png
   Path=/home/USER/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/HeidiSQL
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Categories=Wine;
   StartupNotify=true
   StartupWMClass=heidisql.exe
   ```

   (of course you need to change the paths after `Exec=`, `Icon=` and `Path=` with the appropriate ones. `StartupWMClass=` is not compulsory but having this entry pointed to application executable filename fixes issue with unity launcher showing generic wine app icon when the app is running)
4. Add the icon to the launcher. Either go to `/home/USER/.local/share/applications` using the file browser, look for the HeidiSQL icon and drag it to the launcher, or search for HeidiSQL in Dash and drag the icon from there. (as Dash might contain two identical icons for HeidiSQL, and only one is the right one, I suggest the first method)

For more information about `.desktop` files, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles.

Comment: HeidiSQL works great with wine (good luck, I found no similarly smart SQL client for linux...), yet the font in the lower pane (SQL log) seems broken. The characters look somewhat pseudo-monospaced. Is there a wine setting to correct for this?

Comment: Easy to solve ... if you know where to look: Run `winetricks` (install, if not yet installed), select "Select the default wineprefix" -> "Install Font" -> all fonts. Done.

Comment: You can also use the `128x128` icon to make it look nicer.

Comment: I'm getting an "Error while loading the archive" when opening any of the installers.

Comment: without wine is there any chance to install the .deb file of HeidiSQL in Linux mint

Answer (score 1):

I just installed HeidiSQL 9.4.0.5151 using the 32-bit installer with Wine on my Ubuntu 16.04. An icon was placed directly on my desktop. I looked and found the following:

```
~/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs/HeidiSQL/HeidiSQL.desktop
```

So the above answer containing information on how to do this is not needed.

Double-clicking on the HeidiSQL desktop icon runs HeidiSQL under Wine with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends wine-staging
$ sudo apt-get install winehq-staging
```

[Source](http://linuxg.net/install-wine-1-9-on-ubuntu/)

```
cd ~/.wine/drive_c/<your path>/
/opt/wine-staging/bin/wine file.exe
```

[Wine Usage](https://github.com/wine-compholio/wine-staging/wiki/Usage)

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu softwares, lookup for PlayOnLinux. You can install many windows software on it including heidiSQL. It creates icon and stuff automatically you just have to do next, next.

I find this much more easier for myself.